# HLW8032 UART sends random data ( Registers Overflow often)

Tags: serial, esp8266, softwareserial, uart

I designed  my own version of smart socket just like the Sonoff with power metering chip HLW8032. And when I read the data in ESP-12F the data doesn't have a fixed format.
To troubleshoot the issue, I bought [**HLW8032 Breakout Board**](https://www.electrodragon.com/product/energy-meter-hlw8032-breakout-board/) and analyzed the data sent by HLW8032, and I found the results are the same as the board I designed.

And that made me think that I may be reading the data from the Serial port the wrong way.

HLW8032 sends 24 Bytes on the serial and the format should be like this:

```
F2 5A 02 DA 78 07 1A E0 00 3D 3B 03 EC F5 4C C4 58 9C 2A 39 61 00 00 79 
F2 5A 02 DA 78 07 1A E0 00 3D 3B 03 EC F5 4C C4 58 9D C2 9F 61 00 00 78
```

The data that I receive is in this format,

```
F2 5A 2 D3 70 6 BC D4 0 3D 4F 4 98 B4 4D F2 5A 2 D3 70 6 AA 59 0 
3D 4F 4 98 B4 4D E1 80 FB EC 17 61 0 1 38 0 3D 4F 4 98 B4 4D E1 80 
FD 84 7D 61 0 1 38 F2 5A 2 D3 70 6 AA 59 F2 5A 2 D3 70 6 AA 59 0 
3D 4F 4 98 B4 4D E1 80 FE FF 1 61 0 1 38 2 D3 70 6 AA 59 0 3D 4F 
4 98 B4 4D E1 80 FE FF 1 61 0 1 38 F2 5A 1 61 0 1 38 F2 5A 2 D3 
70 6 AA 59 0 3D 4F 4 98 B4 4D E1 80 FE FF F2 5A 2 D3 70 6 AA 59 0 
3D 4F 4 98 B4 4D E1 80 FE FF 1 61 0 1 38 0 3D 4F 4 98 B4 4D E1 80 
FE FF 1 61 0 1 38 F2 5A 2 D3 70 6 AA 59 38 F2 5A 2 D3 70 6 AA 59 
0 3D 4F 4 98 B4 4D E1 80 FE FF 1 61 0 1 F2 5A 2 D3 70 6 AA 59 0 
3D 4F 4 98 B4 4D E1 80 FE FF 1 61 0 1 38 4F 4 98 B4 4D E1 80 10 1B 
D4 61 0 1 39 F2 5A 2 D3 70 6 AA 59 0 3D F2 5A 2 D3 70 6 AA 59 0 
3D 4F 4 98 B4 4D E1 80 13 4E 9E 61 0 1 39 F2 5A 2 D3 70 6 AA 59 0 
3D 4F 4 98 B4 4D E1 80 14 E8 3 61 0 1 39 E1 80 16 82 67 61 0 1 39 
F2 5A 2 D3 70 6 AA 59 0 3D 4F 4 98 B4 4D F2 5A 2 D3 70 6 AA 59 0
```

We can see that the registers overflows again and again.
The code that I use to read the data is:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define BAUD_RATE 4800

SoftwareSerial swSer(13, 12);

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(BAUD_RATE);
  swSer.begin(BAUD_RATE);
}

byte data[24];
void loop() 
{
  if (swSer.available() > 0) {
    int a = swSer.readBytes(data, 24);
    yield();
  }

  // Display
  for (int i=0;i<24;i++)
  {
    Serial.print(data[i],HEX);
    Serial.print(" ");
  }
  Serial.println();
}
```

Schematic:
[image]

I feel that there is no issue in my hardware design, and the issue seems to be in the sketch.

---

What can be the possible problem with my setup?

---

How do I make the output of HLW8032 Stable with no overflow of registers?

---

Is there any library someone can recommend me to read the data from HLW8032 on **SoftwareSerial**?

**Note:** After some troubleshooting I found that delay() cause the problem to be more worse. And won't receive a stream of Bytes whose first byte , second nibble is **F** like F2, F4, as from the datasheet , first four bits are 1s by default.

Comment: It could be that the data is being sent too rapidly (each byte too close together) for SoftwareSerial to be able to cope with it. The only cure would be to not use software serial, but to use an Arduino with the resources you need to connect the device properly

Comment: @Majenko Yes, But as the required Baud rate for HLW8032 is 4800bps, and that is quite low. I searched about better alternatives to SoftwareSerial, and found there is **AltSoftSerial** and I read someone said as to be better than SoftwareSerial for lower baud rates. I gave it a try and the result is the same. Since the chip I'm using is ESP8266 and it only have one HardwareSerial, and I'm using that for Debug logs.

Comment: The ESP8266 has two hardware UARTs, not one. Although, you may find that the RX pin isn't exposed on whatever board you have - or if it is, it's not labelled as it.

Comment: I would never recommend using any form of SoftwareSerial ever. If you can't do it in hardware on your chosen board / platform, then you are using the wrong board / platform.

Comment: Use the `Serial1` object in the same way that you would use the `Serial` object.

Comment: error: 'Serial1' was not declared in this scope. (PlatformIO)

Comment: @Majenko and due to limitations of the ESP8266, only UART 0 is capable of receiving data.

Comment: Well that's [expletive deleted] then isn't it? Upgrade to an ESP32 then.  The ESP8266's peripheral offerings have always been sadly lacking.

Comment: which version of the esp8266 boards package do you use? what pins do you use for SoftwareSerial? what esp8266 module do you have? Serial1 must be available. you don't need receive data for debug prints

Comment: @Juraj     I'm not using any board(like NodeMCU , Wesmos D1 etc). I'm using my own board which has an ESP-12F module. I use GPIO13 and GPIO12 for the SoftwareSerial.     Serial1 isn't available. I need debug prints , since it's  the first Rev  of the board that I designed, and I must debug and see everything.

Comment: @Juraj   But for understanding and troubleshooting the Issue , I got an Arduino UNO board and HLW8032 Breakout board ,  and it has the same result as my board. I've been using SoftwareSerial for quite many applications even receiving data from RS232 port, I never been in any trouble,

Comment: @Majenko   An esp8266 SoC has two hardware UARTs , UART 0, and UART 1.                           UART 1 is not capable of receiving data. That's why Serial1 is not defined for esp8266 based boards. That's where I'll follow your advice and Upgrade to and ESP32

Comment: https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html?highlight=serial1#serial

Comment: @Juraj Thanks you so much!! That's too comprehensive information. I gave it a try and see  the results.

Comment: @Majenko   It is not an issue of SoftwareSerial. I tested the HLW8032 on the Hardware Serial of Arduino Mega using that code and the results are the same that is the registers overflows. Then I used an [HLW8032 Library](https://github.com/ocrobot/HLW8032) which only works on HardwareSerial, and the values are perfect. The way the library reads Serial is quite different. It's annoying me why it's making issues using readBytes() with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I swaped UART0 to GPIO15 (TX) and GPIO13 (RX), (Luckily the Tx of HLW8032 is connected to GPIO13 in my hardware design and This is the UART0 RX pin after swap). Then I analyzed the data coming and the results were the same as of that SoftwareSerial i.e the registers overflows.

Then I used an [HLW8032 Library](https://github.com/Khaalidi/HLW8032) (Which I've forked and will make changes for improvements) which only works on HardwareSerial, and the values are perfect. The way the library reads Serial is quite different.

So in short my issue resolved using two things:

1. I swaped UART0 to GPIO15 and GPIO13 using `Serial.swap()`
2. Used a [library for the HLW8032](https://github.com/Khaalidi/HLW8032)

Thanks to [@Juraj](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/37622/juraj) who provided the useful [link](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html?highlight=serial1#serial) about Serial Swap in ESP8266.

> Serial uses UART0, which is mapped to pins GPIO1 (TX) and GPIO3 (RX). Serial may be remapped to GPIO15 (TX) and GPIO13 (RX) by calling Serial.swap() after Serial.begin. Calling swap again maps UART0 back to GPIO1 and GPIO3.

```
#include "HLW8032.h"

HLW8032 HL;

void setup()
{
    HL.begin(Serial,4);   
    Serial.begin(4800);
    Serial.swap(); 
}

unsigned int V;
void loop()
{
    HL.SerialReadLoop();   

    if(HL.SerialRead == 1)   
    {
    V = HL.GetVol();
    }
}
```

With this I can't print and see my debug prints on  GPIO1 (TX) and GPIO3 (RX), but at least without changing a bit in the hardware, my design works fine.